# É correto usar a tag Input dentro de uma tag Label?

Tags: html, input, label

Eu estava dando uma olhada no tutorial do [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs.asp), onde está ensinando a usar o `input` do tipo `checkbox` no Bootstrap.

De acordo com um dos exemplos, vi o seguinte código:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox disabled">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="" disabled>Option 3</label>
</div>
```

Eu nunca tinha usado `label` com algum `input` dentro, pois eu achava mais lógico usar a `label` para identificar o que o `input` faz, um do lado do outro. Mas agora que vi no W3Schools e o próprio site do Bootstrap *ensina* a fazer colocando o `input` dentro do `label`.

Até agora eu só vi esse exemplo com `checkbox`, mas eu tenho algumas dúvidas

A minha dúvida é:

- Isso não seria incorreto? Pois isso me soa como colocar um `input` dentro de um `h1`?
- Qualquer `input` pode ser colocado dentro de um `label`? Ou apenas o `checkbox`? Ou isso é *invenção de moda* do Bootstrap?
- Se isso é válido, é válido apenas para o HTML 5, ou para outras versões, de acordo com o W3c?

<sub>**nota**: Não adicionei a tab [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap), pois a pergunta não é sobre esse assunto, ele é apenas uma citação</sub>

Comment: Você ja tem dois problemas de cara, 1º - W3Schools só serve para aprender o básico, não como regra (eles ensinam a empilhar os blocos, não significa que estão empilhados certo). 2º - Bootstrap é praticamente uma gambiarra para você deixar o site "bonitinho" quando não tem tempo para fazer o design decente.

Comment: [Pode verificar se um documento hmtl é válido no validador w3](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea). Eu meti lá o seu `html` e ele é valido.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, é correto se for o que deseja. [Está na especificação do HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL) e [na especificação do HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) que pode colocar `<input>` antes, depois ou dentro da *tag*/controle `<label>`.

Usando desta forma permite que o foco no `<input>` se dê quando o `<label>` é acionado de alguma forma (um atalho, por exemplo). è muito mais fácil usar uma página montada desta forma.

Não funciona se estiver usando tabelas para *layout*, mas você não faz isso, certo?

Experimente clicar em todos os *label* abaixo. Claro que o é possível simular isso nas duas primeiras com atributo `for`, então a escolha depende do resultado desejado, principalmente com relação à organização do *layout* e a estilização aplicada com CSS.

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value=""><label>Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>Option 2</label><input type="checkbox" value="">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 3</label>
</div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/InputLabel.html).

Answer (score 7):

Adicionar um label a um controle (text, checkbox, radio, select) é um forma de permitir acessibilidade da sua página, lembre que algumas pessoas tem problemas com coordenação motora, logo não é nada simples acertar o click em naquela caixinha do checkbox, é mais fácil click no label (texto/descrição) para des/marcar. Sites do governo são obrigados a fornecer mecanismos acessibilide.  Isso já existia no html4.

Veja a diferença de comportamento entre as duas opções:

```html
Marque Aqui sem label <input type="checkbox"> 
<label>Marque Aqui com label <input type="checkbox"></label>
```

Comment: Hum... Nesse caso, nem precisou do `for`